# Bar chart with 2 variable on x axis and 1 in Y axis

Tags: sas

I want to create a bar chart on yearly death count (based on gender). I want to plot gender and year on x axis and count on Y axis. Can you kindly  help how to modify the below code?

```
TITLE 'DEATH GRAPH BY GENDER';
PROC SGPLOT DATA = DREPORT;
  VBAR deathcount / GROUP = gender GROUPDISPLAY = CLUSTER;
RUN;
```

I am not able to put deathyear in the Y axis. Kindly frame the code.

Comment: You may need to be a little more descriptive of your problem. i.e. language and libraries used, specific outcome etc.

Comment: Please include data and describe/show what the current graph outputs. Code looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

The `VBAR` variable is the mid-point values to show on the horizontal axis.

- Are you sure that is what you want ?
- Do you really want to know how many times a give death count occurred over all the years ?

You probably want `deathcount` as the `response`

Consider this example:

```
data have_raw;
  do id = 1 to 1000;
    gender = substr('MF',1 + 2 * ranuni(123),1);
    year = 2019 - floor (30 * ranuni(123));
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table have as
  select year, gender, count(*) as deathcount
  from have_raw
  group by year, gender
  ;

proc sgplot data=have;
  vbar gender 
  / response=deathcount 
    group=year
    groupdisplay=cluster
  ;
run;
```

[image]